# APFS snapshot specific volume

Tags: apfs

Does anyone know how to make an APFS snapshot of a specific APFS volume?

`tmutil` doesn't seem to have that option and `tmutil` snapshot make snapshots for all APFS volumes.
`diskutil` neither

But for sure it's possible, hopefully there is a tool for this.

Comment: Only apps (e.g. Carbon Copy Cloner) with a special Apple entitlement can make snapshots.